# Refreshing an answer to a closed question after an edit removes the close message

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

When a question with answers to it gets closed it displays the close reason with the people that voted for it. However when an answer is edited after the post is closed and you use the inline refresh to get the updated answer, it will remove the close message. Refreshing the page will display the message again.

Steps to reproduce:

- Pose a horrible question
- Get an unfinished answer
- Get the question locked
- Wait until the answer gets updated
- Use the inline answer refresh
  [image]

Case in point (the Grinch that saved StackExchange):

**INITIAL SITUATION**

> [image]

**OOPS AN EDIT OCCURRED**

> [image]

**WHERE DID IT GO?**

> [image]

Comment: I would probably +1 this, but I am really confused by all the screenshots.

Comment: @bluefeet: I have provided much clearer screenshots instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't know what they looked like before, but I'm also confused.

Comment: Servy made it a lot clearer with his magic. Appearantly it's a duplicate.. I looked trough the suggested questions, google and the SE search and couldn't find a duplicate. Apologies.

Comment: I would recommend downloading an application called Jing. It will allow you to highlight certain attributes of screen shots without looking like clown make up. Not trying to sound mean it would just make your point more clear.

Comment: That is an *epic* red freehand circle.

Comment: I have always shown artistic talent.