# lost duplicate marking on question after editing some answers

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, edits

I am sure I found this 3 times at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-java-program). Someone marks my question as below:

> This question may already have an answer here:
>
> Why is return needed even after System.exit(0); 8 answers

I got about 7 answers on it and updated answers by answerers again and again. I have noticed that after an answer is edited, my question lost the above marking for duplicate. I think "..Ah they have remove the duplicate mark!". But after refreshing my browser, my question becomes as you see now. So, I describe it as a bug here.

Comment: Possible duplicate from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210822/refreshing-an-answer-to-a-closed-question-after-an-edit-removes-the-close-messag) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184642/why-does-the-questions-closed-status-disappear-when-clicking-to-load-a-new-edit).

Comment: by the way , I can support it with images :)